# Formatting time math and logic

Tags: python

i have a value in seconds from uptime server

```
301142 ( seconds ) = 3 days 11 hours 39 minutes 02 seconds
```

or

```
2754 ( seconds ) = 45 minutes 54 seconds
```

the best function that i have made is returning me wrong values

```
def format_time(self, milliseconds = 0):
        # format mocroseconds to day,hour,seconds
        seconds, milliseconds = divmod(milliseconds,1000)
        minutes, seconds = divmod(seconds, 60)
        hours, minutes = divmod(minutes, 60)
        days, hours = divmod(hours, 24)
        seconds = seconds + milliseconds/1000
        return days, hours, minutes, seconds
```

some one can help me please?

Comment: Well do you have the value in seconds or milliseconds? You say the former but your code uses the latter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of useful library that you can use, for example:

```
from datetime import timedelta
"{:0>8}".format(str(timedelta(seconds=301142)))
# Output : '3 days, 11:39:02'
```

Answer (score 0):

I really think someone can write better, but this thing always worked for me and didn’t fail:

```
import datetime

def format_dt(time_in_seconds):
    dt = datetime.datetime.fromordinal(1) - \
         datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(0) + \
         datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time_in_seconds)
    return dt.day - 1, dt.hour, dt.minute, dt.second
```